# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Привет, использую java 1.6, соответственно беру sqljdbc4.jar. Под отладчиком всё срабатывает, а вот самостоятельный запуск выдаёт ошибку "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" вот на этой строчке:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

вот код этого куска:

```
Connection conn = null;  
Statement statement = null;  
ResultSet rs = null;
try{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://<server_name>:1433;databaseName=<db_name>;integratedSecurity=true;user=<user>;password=<***>";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    statement = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    rs = statement.executeQuery(query1 + itemTag + query2);
    while(rs.next()){
        String number = rs.getString(1); 
        tableItem.setText(7, number);
        break;
    }
}catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally {  
    if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}  
    if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}  
    if (conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}  
}
```

Казалось бы, нужно прописать sqljdbc4.jar в classpath, однако, это не помогло почему-то. На всякий случай проверил расположение "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", но тогда бы и в отладчике не работало...

Comment: добавьте информацию о том как вы собирает проект и как именно запускаете.

Comment: И как именно указывали classpath.

Comment: Использую Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers Version: Indigo Service Release 2 Build id: 20120216-1857. Собираю плагин для другого приложения. Сам код подключения внутри статичного метода. В проекте создал отдельную директорию lib, туда сложил внешние джарники, в том числе sqljdbc4.jar, в разделе Runtime проекта, в разделе Classpath, добавил все эти внешние джарники. Любопытно, что при этих же манипуляциях остальные библиотеки, перечисленные в Classpath, отрабатывают нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Удалось побороть путём повторной вставки sqljdbc4.jar в папку lib проекта, повторного внесения пути lib/sqljdbc4.jar в classpath, так же перенёс функцию выполнения запроса в отдельный класс проекта для вспомогательных функций и всё заработало... кароче, просто надо было всё несколько раз отключить/подключить эту библиотеку и оно заработало...